# issue while building docker

Tags: docker, npm

Hi I have a DockerFile for node-red where I'm using this image

```
FROM node:16-buster-slim
```

and a stage as follows:

```
RUN npm -i install && npm audit fix --force && npm run build && rm -rf node_modules && npm install --production
```

While building this, I'm getting error:

```
#23 66.90 markdown  *
#23 66.90 Regular Expression Denial of Service in markdown - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-wx77-rp39-c6vg
#23 66.90 fix available via `npm audit fix`
#23 66.90 node_modules/markdown
#23 66.90 
#23 66.90 marked  <=4.0.9
#23 66.90 Severity: high
#23 66.90 Multiple Content Injection Vulnerabilities in marked - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-9cw2-jqp5-7x39
#23 66.90 Moderate severity vulnerability that affects marked - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-7px7-7xjx-hxm8
#23 66.90 Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in marked - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-5v2h-r2cx-5xgj
#23 66.90 Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in marked - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-rrrm-qjm4-v8hf
#23 66.90 Sanitization bypass using HTML Entities in marked - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-vfvf-mqq8-rwqc
#23 66.90 Regular Expression Denial of Service in marked - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-x5pg-88wf-qq4p
#23 66.90 VBScript Content Injection in marked - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-cfjh-p3g4-3q2f
#23 66.90 Regular Expression Denial of Service in marked - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-hjcp-j389-59ff
#23 66.90 fix available via `npm audit fix`
#23 66.90 node_modules/jsdoc3/node_modules/marked
#23 66.90 
#23 66.90 minimatch  <=3.0.4
#23 66.90 Severity: high
#23 66.90 Regular Expression Denial of Service in minimatch - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-hxm2-r34f-qmc5
#23 66.90 minimatch ReDoS vulnerability - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-f8q6-p94x-37v3
#23 66.90 fix available via `npm audit fix`
#23 66.90 node_modules/jsdoc3/node_modules/minimatch
#23 66.90 
#23 66.90 sanitize-html  <=2.3.1
#23 66.90 Severity: moderate
#23 66.90 Improper Input Validation in sanitize-html - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-mjxr-4v3x-q3m4
#23 66.90 Improper Input Validation in sanitize-html - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-rjqq-98f6-6j3r
#23 66.90 fix available via `npm audit fix`
#23 66.90 node_modules/sanitize-html
#23 66.90   ink-docstrap  >=1.0.0
#23 66.90   Depends on vulnerable versions of sanitize-html
#23 66.90   node_modules/docstrap
#23 66.90 
#23 66.90 taffydb  *
#23 66.90 Severity: high
#23 66.90 TaffyDB can allow access to any data items in the DB - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-mxhp-79qh-mcx6
#23 66.90 fix available via `npm audit fix`
#23 66.90 node_modules/taffydb
#23 66.90 
#23 66.90 underscore  1.3.2 - 1.12.0
#23 66.90 Severity: critical
#23 66.90 Arbitrary Code Execution in underscore - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-cf4h-3jhx-xvhq
#23 66.90 fix available via `npm audit fix`
#23 66.90 node_modules/jsdoc3/node_modules/underscore
#23 66.90 node_modules/nomnom/node_modules/underscore
#23 66.90   nomnom  >=1.6.0
#23 66.90   Depends on vulnerable versions of underscore
#23 66.90   node_modules/nomnom
#23 66.90 
#23 66.90 11 vulnerabilities (2 low, 2 moderate, 4 high, 3 critical)
#23 66.90 
#23 66.90 To address all issues, run:
#23 66.90   npm audit fix
#23 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c npm -i install && npm audit fix --force && npm run build && rm -rf node_modules && npm install --production" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

While using node version 14, This issue didn't came and build passed successfully but while trying to upgrade to 16, This issue is coming.

When I tried splitting this stage I found that npm audit fix --force is showing error. Can Anyone help me understand why is this happening ? I'm currently new to docker. Thank you

Comment: The `exit code: 1` error you quote just boils down to "it didn't work"; do you have the entire error, and do you know which part of that `RUN` command is failing?

Comment: Yes I've updated the error. I'm getting that.